# How can I change the location center of a map using Leaflet API?

Tags: maps, location, centering, leaflet

My map (Mapbox) takes up the whole background of the site so the center is in the middle of the site.  But the focus of the map for the user is on the right side because I have content overlapping the map on the left side.  When leaflet grabs the location, it's from the center of the map, but it would be more convenient if I could set it to grab the location from the center of the right third of the site, so that way the user won't be centering the map on targets bordering content on the left half of the site.

Is there a way I could set the center or location focus of the leaflet API for the map?

Here's how I have it set up currently,

```
mapOptions: {
        maxZoom: 18,
        zoomControl: false,
        worldCopyJump: true 
},

createMap: function() {
        Map.map =  L.map('map', Map.mapOptions);
        Map.layer = L.mapbox.tileLayer(Map.mapID, {
                unloadInvisibleTiles: true,
        }).addTo(Map.map);              
        Map.map.locate({setView: true});
        Map.map.addControl(L.mapbox.geocoderControl(Map.mapID));
        new L.Control.Zoom({ position: 'topright' }).addTo(Map.map);
},
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a combo of `panBy()` and `getSize()` to offset the map the width of your overlay.

Here's a snippet that should get you a started:

```
// Calculate the offset
var offset = map.getSize().x*0.15;
// Then move the map
map.panBy(new L.Point(-offset, 0), {animate: false});
```

In my example, my overlay is 33% of the width of the map. So I grab the size of the map area, then multiple by 0.15 (this was based on some experimenting to see what the best offset amount was) and use `panBy()` to offset the map center.

Here's a [full example](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/WWBgh/).

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple markers and want to center the map in their bounds and at the same time you have overlapping container, you can use the **fitBounds** options (paddingTopLeft, paddingBottomRight, padding).

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-paddingtopleft

Answer (score 2):

First you will need to know the lat and long of the point on the map you want to center on. Then it is simple, just call Map.map.setView passing in your coordinates and zoom level.
Api reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-set-methods

If you don't know your coordinates then you can find it by trial and error, just create a marker and add it to the map.

Comment: setView() is exactly what I looked for, which is described in your link.

Answer (score 1):

Found this solution by [ghybs](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/61375/ghybs) over on [GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170702/change-the-center-point-of-leaflet/170703#170703) which helped me solve this problem:

- [Leaflet-active-area](https://github.com/Mappy/Leaflet-active-area)

  > This plugin allows you to use a smaller portion of the map as an active area. All positioning methods (setView, fitBounds, setZoom) will be applied on this portion instead of the all map.