# How to centralize and change the center of the leaflet map dynamically

Tags: leaflet

I have a map that covers the entire screen and I have a layer that overlays the map. That layer goes from bottom to top.
the user interacts with this layer by clicking on different options and these options draw markers on the map.

When I centralize the map, the markers are hidden behind the layer that superimposes the map, thus eliminating the visibility of the marker.

How could I centralize the map and then move it one third above the layer?
This question is a remake of
[How can I change the location center of a map using Leaflet API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758256/how-can-i-change-the-location-center-of-a-map-using-leaflet-api)

Try doing it this way

```
var offset = map.getSize().y * 0.15;
map.panBy(new L.Point(0, -offset), {animate: false});
```

But every time I click on an option in the layer to create a marker, the map moves and I lose the center.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t2xty7p2/17/)
[image]

Excuse the example image 
The idea is that after the map makes the setView place its center above the blue layer that superimposes the map so as not to hide the markers.

Comment: Really not sure about what you are trying to achieve… Maybe try adding some sketches, to make it clearer?

Comment: You might be interested in [Change the center point of leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170702/change-the-center-point-of-leaflet)

Comment: It could be very useful, I'm going to review it.
Thank you. @ghybs

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you find a solution?